# Downvoting question as "dumb", but no one can answer it?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655716/codebehind-cant-find-control that has a -2 rating, but no one has yet to answer it.  Both the downvotes happened when the user assumed I hadn't tried other results, and there is still no solution to the question.  To me, this is a very good question, but the downvotes hurt my score.  What can I do about it?

Comment: So downvoting should only be allowed if someone has an answer?

Comment: *"Both the downvotes happened when the user assumed I hadn't tried other results"* ... why did they assume that? <-- hint

Comment: No, if the question really WAS dumb, this would be fine.  But seeing as there doesn't seem to be a REASON for the downvote I question what to do about it.

Comment: Bart, they assumed that because this situation has happened before.  However, none of the previous solutions worked, which is why I asked a new question with my specific details.

Comment: One hint to take is, if it takes a lot of comments to clarify the question, something may not be at its best.

Comment: You should add in your posts what you have tried and what hasn't worked. That will show users that you have, in fact, researched the issue and tried to solve yourself.

Comment: You have absolutely no clue why someone downvoted until someones explains why. Nobody did on your question. So all you bring up is just pure speculation.

Comment: What I meant is that people assume certain things if you don't take away the basis for those assumptions. I.e. from the very start don't just clearly state the problem you're facing, but also what you have done to try and resolve it. That takes away any reason for others to ask "did you try X?" and for you to say "sure, that's the first thing I did".

Comment: Note: Use '@' to notify the users you are addressing in your comments. For example @AllWoods is the correct way to ping you.

Comment: a question being un-answerable is **not** a good thing

Comment: Also, you should not assume *who* voted for your question. Others could have been reading and voting the same time the people commented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given that asp.net is not my forte, I'll keep this somewhat general. I'm sure others can provide more concrete hints at what to include, update or adjust.

> Both the downvotes happened when the user assumed I hadn't tried other results

Let's say you're right there. (Though you're pretty much assuming about both the reason as well as the downvoters) The solution is pretty simple. Don't give them any reason to assume anything.

If you write a clear concise question, that's brilliant. But it's often not sufficient. We generally don't want to put effort into an answer only to hear "yeah, I tried that already. That didn't solve my problem". If you're not telling us what  it is you did to try and resolve your problem, we're going to assume you haven't tried it.

So state what you've tried. If you found a great question on SO that contains a potential solution, but it didn't work for you, state so. Not only will it be clear to others what you have tried to do, but at the same time you've linked your specific problem to a solution that might help others.

Looking at the question itself, as well as the comments below it, it has gone through several iterations to improve it. Being very minimal at first, information has been continuously added and several back-and-forths were necessary in the comments to get to a more clear situation. It's in the end great that it happened, but it's also an indication the question wasn't all that good.

Keep in mind that we know nothing about your situation, your train of thought, and what you have tried before posting your question. Keep it short, keep it to the point, but don't forget to get us on that train of thought by giving us a short summary of the trip you've taken to where you're at.